# highlighting a text without using original text in lucene.net?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

How can I highlight my searched text without using the original text in lucene.net? I just want to used an index and the text is indexed  by using  the field termvector with postion offsets?

Answer (score 1):

if you index your field with "Store.YES" and "TermVector.WITH_POSTIONS_OFFSETS"
you can use FastVectorHighlighter in contrib to highlight search results without referencing original text.

Comment: Thanks...but  I have tried with "Store.YES" but i dont want to index  with "Store.yes"?is there any alternative? and furthermore would you please tell me  how can i highlight without referencing the original text?